# Getting Error while using Math.Sqrt function in C#

Tags: c#, math.sqrt

---

In the program given below, Math.Sqrt function is throwing an error that is
"Expression denotes a `variable', where a`method group' was expected."
What seems to be problematic here?

---

```
using System;
class program{
    static void Main(){
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the sides(a,b,c) of a triangle  :");
        int a = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        int b = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        int c = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        double s = (a+b+c)/2;     
        double area = Math.Sqrt(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c));
        if (a==b&&b==c){
            Console.WriteLine("This is an Equilateral trangle");
        }
        else if(a==b&&b!=c||a!=b&&b==c){
            Console.WriteLine("This is an Isosceles trangle");
        }
        else{
            Console.WriteLine("This is an Scalene trangle");
        }
    }
}here
```

Comment: `s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Did you mean to write your expression as `s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)`? C# will not assume a multiplication.

Comment: `double s = (a + b + c) / 2.0;` please, notice `.0`

Answer (score 1):

C# will not assume a multiplication in the same way you write down an equation, and instead will see `s(s-a)` as a function called `s` that takes a parameter of `s-a`. You need to explicitly state the multiplication sign:

```
double area = Math.Sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
```